# WP Loop not pulling correct info

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to make an accordion for a question and answer section.  The code works, however, when I try and place it into the WP Loop I am encountering problems.  The loop is pulling the correct posts, but is only showing the answer for the latest post, regardless on which post I select.  I assume the problem is with my code in lines 29-33.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O05mK.jpg)

Comment: It would be better if you could provide code snipped inside the question in text format.

Comment: Inside the question, using [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: <?php   $args = array ('post_type' => 'faq');  
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);?>  
<?php  if ($the_query->have_posts() ) :  
while ($the_query->have_posts() ) :  
$the_query->the_post(); ?>  
    
<div class="half">  
<div class="tab">  
<input id="tab" type="checkbox" name="tabs">  
<label for="tab"><?php the_field('question'); ?></label>  
<div class="tab-content">  
<p><?php the_field('answer'); ?></p>  
</div> <!—- end tab-content—->  
</div> <!—- end tab—->  
</div> <!—- end half—->  
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

Comment: Applogies, this is my first time posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all the answers are also in the 'post_type' => 'faq' ?

Comment: The post works fine when I display it as a normal post.  It pulls the correct custom fields and displays with the correct post.  Somehow when I turn it into a checkbox format it is only pulling the answer from the last post.

Comment: I have figured out that the problem is with my CSS animation.  All the CSS is targeted to the first post shown?